# Spark write the output to one file in foreach batch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Are there any ways that can control spark write the output to one file even in foreach batch?

I have a spark job which need read data from kafka and then save three keys(appName, moduleName, serviceName) to S3, you can treat them as a primary key, so I want to append them to one file when continuously read data from kafka.

Any idea pls?

```
Dataset<Row> rowDataset = dataset.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
                .select(from_csv(col("value"), SpanSchema4Csv.spanStructType, new Map.Map1<>("escape", "\"")).as("data"))
                .select(col("data.TAGS_APPNAME").as("applicationname"), col("data.TAGS_MODULENAME").as("modulename"),
                        col("data.LOCALENDPOINT_SERVICENAME").as("microservicename"))
                ;
DataStreamWriter<Row> rowDataStreamWriter = rowDataset.writeStream();
DataStreamWriter<Row> option = rowDataStreamWriter.foreachBatch((row, time) -> {
            row.persist();
            row.coalesce(1).write().mode(OutputMode.Append().toString()).format("json")
                    .save("file:///D:/sparkData/CalculateFilterFromKafka/result");
            row.unpersist();
}
```

Comment: Even with the coalesce to one it doesn't write in one file ?

Also the persist and unpersist are useless here.

Comment: @RobertReynolds With coalesce (1) it can write in one file in a batch, but what i want is write in one file in multiple batch, btw i just use the persist and unpersist  from the official website example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this :

```
        DataStreamWriter<Row> option = rowDataStreamWriter.foreachBatch((row, time) -> {
row.coalesce(1).write().mode(SaveMode.Append()).format("json").save("file:///D:/sparkData/CalculateFilterFromKafka/result");
}
```

The enum containing the value Apped is SaveMode and you don't have to call toString() on it.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html#Append